# Fill DataGridView row by row using background worker

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, datagridview, backgroundworker

When user open the form and there is a data grid in the form its take a second to load all data. It looks like my app hangs in a little time.

So I want to show the data in the data grid view row by row to show the user the data is fetching from the database.

I'm using this code:

```
connection.open()
dim ds as new dataset
dim adp as sqldataadapter = new sqldataadapter("select * from table1",connection)
adp.fill(ds,"table1")
datagridview.datasource=ds
datagridview.datamember=table
datagridview.refresh()
connection.close()
```

How can I do it?

Comment: You can't.  The call to `Fill` that you're making doesn't return until all the data has been retrieved.  You could use a data reader instead but then you'd end up making the load take significantly longer.  What you should be doing is changing the cursor to the hourglass or equivalent.  That has been the Windows standard for indicating to the user that background work is occurring for decades.

Comment: To do what jmcilhinney suggested you can use `datagridview.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor`.

Comment: so how i can show the data in datagridview row by row ?